# Visual Studio 2008 does not Remember my "Default Page" for Web Sites

Tags: boot, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition, I have a recurring issue that I deal with every morning.  I bring up a web site (by opening the .sln file) and it fails to remember my "start action" from the last time I worked with the site.  Other developers in the department do *not* have this problem.  I assume this setting is stored in the SLN file, and the SLN file does in fact get committed to revision control, so I would expect the behavior to be consistent across the department, but it is not.  Every time I go into the "Start Options" in the project "Property Pages", it is set as "Use Current Page".

I need it to be set to start at a specifc page, and I need it to remember this forever.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Start Options" is not saved in the .sln file. It is saved in a WebsiteCache folder which is located at:
"User Profile Folder\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebsiteCache" in an xml named "Websites.xml".

For some reason, this folder must be getting cleared on start up in your PC. Hence the issue. Or VS2008 may not be looking into this folder. Only solution is check if the file is really getting cleared & by whom.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am going to start investigating this right now.

Comment: Hmmmm, I think that file somehow got corrupted because I cannot even open it now.  There is no XML data.  I viewed it in a binary editor, and it is 46KB worth of low-values (all bits off).  I think I will try to delete this file and see if it works.

Comment: That was it!  Somehow the file got corrupted and wiped out.  I deleted the file, brought the solution up in VS2008, set the start options, and now I have a valid XML file with one entry.  Thank you very much for your help, Ganesh!